# does it matter what .after() is applied to?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to understand how to best use `after()`, namely what to bind it with. In order to test several scenarios I coded three simple counters which display passing seconds:

- `clock1`: a Label in a Frame (which itself is a child of the root window), binding to the Frame
- `clock2`: a Label in the same Frame as above, binding to root
- `clock3`: a Label in root, binding to root

The actual code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter1 = 0
        self.counter2 = 100
        self.counter3 = 1000
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="clock1")
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="clock2")
        self.label2.pack()
        self.label3 = tk.Label(self.root, text="clock3")
        self.label3.pack()

    def clock1(self):
        self.counter1 += 1
        text = "hello from clock1: {}".format(self.counter1)
        self.label1.configure(text=text)
        self.frame.after(1000, self.clock1)

    def clock2(self):
        self.counter2 += 1
        text = "hello from clock2: {}".format(self.counter2)
        self.label2.configure(text=text)
        self.root.after(1000, self.clock2)

    def clock3(self):
        self.counter3 += 1
        text = "hello from clock3: {}".format(self.counter3)
        self.label3.configure(text=text)
        self.root.after(1000, self.clock3)

a = App()
a.clock1()
a.clock2()
a.clock3()
a.root.mainloop()
```

This code, when run, shows this after 18 seconds:

[image]

This means that all counters are updated. In that case does it matter what `.after()` is applied to? (sorry if this is not the right expression)

In other words `<whatever object exists>.after(time, my_callback)` will work and therefore binding it to the root window is just a convention?

Comment: One reason to bind it to the root window is that it will always be there until you close the application.  If you bind it to a widget, that widget object could easily be removed and your call to `after` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Does it mean that it does not matter what widget it is bound to? (beside the very good point you made regarding the existence of the widget). Also would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it (ideally adding the extra information above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `after` methods of `Tkinter.Tk`, `Tkinter.Label`, `Tkinter.Frame`, etc. are all the same:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> Tkinter.Tk.after is Tkinter.Frame.after
True
>>> Tkinter.Label.after is Tkinter.Tk.after
True
>>> Tkinter.Frame.after is Tkinter.Label.after
True
>>>
```

This is because `after` is a [basic widget method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) that is available on *all* Tkinter widgets.  So, you may call it on whatever one you please and always get the same effect.

That said, I think it would be best to call the `after` method only on the root window object (the main `Tkinter.Tk` instance) because:

1. As you said in your post, that is a very common way of doing it.  If you break this pseudo convention, it may confuse people.
2. Normally, the root window object does not disappear until you explicitly close the application.  In other words, it will always be there.  If you use the `after` method of a child widget, such as a label, the code may break and raise an `AttributeError` if the widget object was ever destroyed.  This could happen if you have an application with dynamic widgets and/or widgets that disappear after a certain condition is met.
3. This is just my opinion, but it seems proper that the main window object is responsible for executing callbacks and managing events.  After all, it represents the application itself.  A label however should be just that: a label.  It should not be concerned with managing the application.